# Presentation properties for list box is not working in Qlikview

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, qlikview

I am relatively new to qlikview and I am working on a app using Qlikview Desktop 10. I have created a new dashboard sheet where in I have added some list boxes. One of the list box is year. I have set its presentation property 'Fixed Number of Columns' as 3 but the data in year is not divided in column wise.

Could  anyone let me know what am doing wrong??

Please find the screenprint of the issue attached.

Dex.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck "Order by Column" and see if that fixes the issue.

/Micke

Comment: Thanks...This has fixed the issue. Can you tell me why the order by column is preventing the breakup into columns?/

Comment: Again it is to do with the size of the object. If the object has enough downwards real estate it will favor that over columns. By unticking it you are telling it to favour rows over columns. You'll see if you make it short and fat without changing the tick box the columns will start generating